Recover data from "stale" process
I had a windowserver crash recently, but my MuseScore 4 Development version was somehow not killed (possibly because it's launched from the command line) and stays in the process list in activity monitor when I logged in again. However, it no longer shows up anywhere graphically, whether in the Dock or Spaces.
I have unsaved work (autosave is 10 minutes I believe). The autosave file is no longer being updated. How can I recover my unsaved work?

Are you able to install Script Debugger or use Script Editor to view this app’s scripting commands and objects? If so, you might have a tangible way to automate saving the document… so sorry you ended up in a pickle like this.

@bmike Unfortunately it seems like MuseScore 4 does not come with any scripting commands. I tried script editor's open dictionary but the app is greyed out.

If you logged out and in again, then surely that would have killed all user processes? MS might have restarted itself, but your data would be lost. TBH, if it's only 10 minutes' work, then I would just do it again, rather than spending more than 10 minutes on trying to recover it.

@benwiggy If MS restarted itself I should see it somewhere. But I don't. Also a windowserver crash is technically different from a log out although I don't know what the specific differences would be. I just find this question interesting because I don't know much about windowserver.

I can only go on what you tell me. You said you "logged in again". That would suggest logging out.
